# Blazor css Isolation doesn't loaded properly when deploy on firebase host

Tags: css, firebase, blazor, blazor-webassembly, firebase-hosting

I deploy my bloazor wasm on firebase host via github actions and the {projectname}.style.css doesn't load properly. instead it show as index.html in chrome inspecter ( but in coverage it said as css but unused 100% ) everything other than Blazor css Isolation (.razor.css) work fine on deply. ( Everything is normal when I debug in localhost. )

I couldn't post my website link here since I haven't secure my apikey on client side yet :(

Below is my actions flow and my firebase.json

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # Install CLI tools
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - name: Install CLI tools
        run: |
          npm install -g terser csso-cli html-minifier

      # Use CLI tools to minify, overwriting existing files
      - name: Minify JavaScript
        run: |
          for i in ./wwwroot/Build/*.js; do
            terser $i --compress --mangle --output $i || exit 1
          done
      - name: Minify CSS
        run: |
          for i in ./wwwroot/css/*.css; do
            csso $i -o $i || exit 1
          done
      - name: Minify HTML
        run: |
          for i in ./wwwroot/*.html; do
            html-minifier $i -o $i || exit 1
          done
      
      # Publish and Deploy
      - name: Publish dotnet
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o release
      - name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ROCKDOMAIN_A1062 }}'
          projectId: rockdomain-a1062
```

And here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "release/wwwroot",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.css",
        "destination": "/css/$0"
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.razor.css",
        "destination": "/shared/$0"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.wasm",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.unityweb",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.br",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Encoding",
            "value": "br"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please feel free to ask if you need any other information
( also I'm new to web development, Thanks in advance )